# prolog program : compares two lists' items and return a list of unique element that are on List1

Tags: prolog

This program compares two lists' items and returns a list with items that are members of first list and are not members of second list. For example: `list1=[a,b,d], list2=[r,a,f,b] ----> result =[a,b]`.

```
go:- comp([y,h,b],[b,t],R),!.

comp([],_,_) :- !.
comp(_,[],_) :- !.
comp([H|T],B,_) :- memberchk(H,B),comp(T,B,_); comp(T,B,R),write([H]).
```

current result is `[h][y]`

result I need should be `[h,y]`

Comment: In your examples : list1=[a,b,d], list2=[r,a,f,b] ----> result =[a,b] ( Seems like intersection ), list1=[y,h,b],list2=[b,t] ----> rezult= [h,y] ( Seems like difference of sets )... Which one you need??

Answer (score 2):

Your request is for a predicate which *returns a list with items that are members of first list and are not members of second list*. But your example:

```
list1=[a,b,d], list2=[r,a,f,b] ----> result =[a,b]
```

Is the result of *returns a list with members that are in both lists* (intersection). I'm assuming you want what you requested, not what your example shows.

In your original, you had:

```
comp(_, [], _).
```

Which would not give a correct result if you queried, say, `comp([a], [], X)` since you're using the "don't care" term, `_`. It's an improper expression of what you probably intended, which is `comp(L, [], L)` (a list is itself if you exclude elements of an empty list from it). In addition, none of your original clauses instantiates a result (all of them have the "don't care" `_` in that position).

A corrected version might look like this:

```
comp([], _, []).
comp(L, [], L).
comp([H|T], S, R) :-
    (   memberchk(H, S)
    ->  comp(T, S, R)
    ;   R = [H|RT],
        comp(T, S, RT)
    ).

?- comp([y,h,b],[b,t],R).
R = [y, h] ;
false.

?-
```

Note that the "false" response after typing `;` means there are no additional solutions.